# Тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Читаю статью в интернете. Знаки препинания расставлены так: "Был какой-то большой церковный праздник — то ли Пасха, то ли Рождество". Но у меня сомнение: разве после "праздник" не двоеточие?

Answer (score 2):

"То ли Пасха, то ли  Рождество" - приложения при слове "праздник". Тире ставится, так как они стоят в конце предложения.

Comment: Добавлю: здесь можно вставить слово "а именно", поэтому нужно тире

Answer (score 1):

то ли Пасха, то ли Рождество - это уточняющее приложение.
Пришел ноябрь – месяц крепких заморозков. (Ю. Казаков)

Answer (score 0):

Если можно вставить слово "а именно", то надо использовать двоеточие (если это БСП). А если можно вставить слово "это", тогда тире (если между подлежащим и сказуемым).

Comment: Не буквально вставить "а именно", а мысленно